# How to evaluate the Jacobian of an arbitrary spacetime transformation?

Tags: physics, jacobian, quantum-field-theory

Under a Poincare transformation $$x^{\prime\mu}=x^\mu+\delta x^\mu=\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\nu}x^\nu+\epsilon^\mu.\tag{1}$$ where first term corresponds to an arbitrary Lorentz transformation and the second term represents a translation in spacetime. I'm trying to calculate the Jacobian of this transformation $J=\det\Big(\frac{\partial x^{\mu\prime}}{\partial x^\lambda}\Big)$. Differentiating (1) we get, $$\frac{\partial x^{\prime\mu}}{\partial x^\lambda}=\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\nu}\delta^{\nu}{}_\lambda+\frac{\partial \epsilon^\mu}{\partial x^\lambda}=\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\lambda}+\partial_\lambda\epsilon^\mu\tag{2}$$ where $\partial_\lambda$ is the shorthand for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\lambda}$.

Next, I'm supposed to take the determinant on both sides. But the determinant of the sum of two matrices A and B is not equal to the sum of the determinants i.e., $$\det(A+B)\neq \det(A)+\det(B).$$ So how do I evaluate $J=\det\Big(\frac{\partial x^{\mu\prime}}{\partial x^\lambda}\Big)$?

Ryder's book on Quantum field theory use the first equality of (1), and write $$\det\Big(\frac{\partial x^{\mu\prime}}{\partial x^\lambda}\Big)=1+\partial_\mu(\delta x^\mu).\tag{3}$$ I have no clue how they got (3). This is not a typo because the same result is also used in Walter Greiner's Field Quantization Eq. 2.47.

Comment: The Jacobian determinant of the Poincaré Transformation $x \mapsto \Lambda x + \epsilon$ is simply $J = \text{det}(\Lambda) = 1$. Why should $\epsilon$ depend on $x$?

Comment: @Dominik How do you get Eq. 3 then? And how do you interpret it?

Comment: This looks like he computes the Jacobian of the transformation $x \mapsto x + (\delta x)(x)$ with $\delta x$ "small", i.e. he keeps only the smallest order.

Comment: @Dominik That would be dimensionally incorrect. Do you suggest that under all Poincare transformation the Jacobian is unity?

Comment: That has the correct dimensionality as the Jacobian here is dimensionless. And yes, the result should be 1 for Poincaré transformations.

Comment: @Dominik All I'm saying is that $x\to x+(\delta x)x$ is dimensionally incorrect. The same $\delta x^\mu$ that appears in Eq. (1), appears in Eq. (3).

Comment: What I meant to indicate with $(\delta x)(x)$ is that $\delta x$ is supposed to be a function of $x$.

Comment: @Michael Rybkin Why reject my edit? This question is apparently not about [field-theory] in mathematical meaning, and is not about [mathematical-physics] which uses advanced mathematical methods to deal with physical problems.